# C++ file reading and string printing

Tags: c++, string, file-io

Why do these two print different things? The first prints abcd but the second prints \x61\x62\x63\x64. What do I need to do to make the line from the file to be read as abcd?

```
    std::string line("\x61\x62\x63\x64");

    ifstream myfile ("myfile.txt"); //<-- the file contains \x61\x62\x63\x64
    std::string line_file;

    getline(myfile,line_file);

    cout << line << endl;
    cout << line_file << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

In c++, the backslash is an escape character, which can be used to represent special characters such as new-lines `\n` and tabs `\t`, or in your case, hexadecimal representations of ASCII characters in *string literals*. If you actually want to store a backslash in c++ you have to escape it: `char c='\\'`. When you read a backslash from a file, it's not treated as an escape character, but as an actual backslash.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the *input file stream* character interpretation:

> File streams opened in binary mode perform input and output operations independently of any format considerations. Non-binary files are known as text files, and **some translations may occur due to formatting of some special characters** (like newline and carriage return characters).
>
> Text file streams are those where the ios::binary flag is not included in their opening mode. These files are designed to store text and thus **all values that are input or output from/to them can suffer some formatting transformations, which do not necessarily correspond to their literal binary value.**

So, the backslashes`'\'` are the most probable reason your `ifstream` is reading and interpreting the bytes from the file differently (as separate `char`acters), as opposed to the `string` that contains information about its value, thus making it non-ambiguous.

For further reading see how [`fstreams`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) work and learn about character literals [backslash escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx).